# cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'drawMatches'

Tags: python, opencv, orb

I want to make a program that iterates on every single picture in a certain folder, extracts its features, and compares it to the next using ORB, although, I'm facing some issues-

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os

# img path of images + extension
pth = "/home/oem/Python37/faces/"
ext = ".jpeg"


#init ORB
orb = cv2.ORB_create()

kp_arr = []
des_arr = []

# getting features of all pics
for pic in os.listdir(pth):
    if pic.endswith(ext):

        img = cv2.imread(pth + pic, 0)
        # setting desired img size for all pic in folder
        img = cv2.resize(img, dsize=[460, 460], fx=0.5, fy=0.5)

        kp, des = orb.detectAndCompute(img, None)
        
        kp_arr.append(kp)
        des_arr.append(des)

        cv2.imshow("win", img)
        cv2.waitKey(0)   

for des in des_arr:
    i = 0
    bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)
    matches = bf.match(des[i], des[i + 1])
    matches = sorted(matches, key=lambda x:x.distance)

    matching_result = cv2.drawMatches(img, kp, img[i + 1], kp[i + 1], matches, None, 3)

    cv2.imshow("matching result", matching_result)


print("KP ARR: ", kp_arr)
print("DES ARR: ", des_arr)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Getting this error when running:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/oem/Python37/iterate.py", line 40, in <module>
    matching_result = cv2.drawMatches(img, kp, img[i + 1], kp[i + 1], matches, None, 3)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'drawMatches'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - Can't parse 'keypoints2'. Input argument doesn't provide sequence protocol
>  - Can't parse 'keypoints2'. Input argument doesn't provide sequence protocol
>  - Can't parse 'keypoints2'. Input argument doesn't provide sequence protocol
>  - Can't parse 'keypoints2'. Input argument doesn't provide sequence protocol
```

Please help, I'm quite new at this..

Comment: you pass _one_ keypoint but it wants a list of keypoints. what was your code supposed to achieve?

Comment: In the second `for` loop, you should be iterating through `kp_arr` and `des_arr` at the same time.

Comment: @rotem. The pic is one image or 2 images?

Comment: Hi, thanks to you all for the replies, @toyotaSupra the "pic" is supposed to be one of the images in the folder, my goal is to iterate over each and get their kp and des into an array out of which I will compare them all to the next. However, it seems not to work